# Simultaneous Variants in Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I'm trying to setup a product that has multiple variant groups that need to be simultaneously selectable and that have their own up-charges.

An example use-case: Say I have a digital product that I'm selling that has multiple license options as follows:

- Standard vs Pro
- Commercial vs Non-Commercial
- License levels based on Users

Each of these items would need to be individually selectable, with appropriate up-charges.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on Slack, the best approach to this currently is to set up all your variants and then use the plugin MultiAdd https://github.com/engram-design/MultiAdd to set up a form that can handle this.

Example code is in the ReadMe there.

It uses a single fast controller to update the cart all in one go, so there's no real speed penalty, and it raises events onMultiAddToCart etc. if needed too.